# Merge Objects where children have overlapping subchildren

Tags: javascript

I'd like to merge two objects together, but in a way that preserves children at any depth.

For example:

```js
const base = {
    a: {
        i: {
            foo: true
        }
    }
};

const add = {
    a: {
        j: {
            foo: false
        }
    },
    b: true
};

const result = {...base, ...add};
console.log(result);
```

Printed result:

```js
{
    a: {
        j: {
            foo: false
        }
    },
    b: true
}
```

Ideally, the result would be

```js
{
    a: {
        i: {
            foo: true
        }
        j: {
            foo: false
        }
    },
    b: true
}
```

Is there a way to... I'm gonna call it "zipper merge" the two objects?

This is for a redux data reducer. I'm going to use null (or a different reducer) to delete if I need to.

Comment: Please add what you tried to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the deep merge function I use for redux in my applications. For most use cases, merging arrays doesn't make sense. So my merge fn overwrites when the incoming value is an array

```js
export const deepMerge = (obj1, obj2 = {}) => {
  const recursiveMerge = (obj, entries) => {
    for (const [key, value] of entries) {
      if (value && typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)) {
        obj[key] = obj[key] ? { ...obj[key] } : {}
        recursiveMerge(obj[key], Object.entries(value))
      } else {
        obj[key] = value
      }
    }
    return obj
  }

  return { ...recursiveMerge(obj1, Object.entries(obj2)) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that recursively merges any number of objects like so:

```js
const base={a:{i:{foo:!0}}},add={a:{j:{foo:!1}},b:!0};
// Note: if multiple objects define a value for the same (nested) key, the
// value in the result will be its value in the last object defining that key
function deepMerge(...objs) {
  const res = {};
  const helper = (o, r = res) => 
    Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => 
      typeof v === 'object' && v !== null ? helper(v, r[k] ??= {}) :
        r[k] = v);
  objs.forEach(o => helper(o));
  return res;
}
console.log(deepMerge(base, add));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Lodash has such a function.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge)

```
_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```

Comment: @bxk21 This implementation doesn't work for redux. This is a mutative operation. You need to have new references for the root of your state tree and any subtrees you modify. Unmitigated's answer works for your use case

Comment: Where do I go to request ECMAScript to implement `Object.assignDeep` ? /s

Comment: @bxk21 Joke or not, you might want to have a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

Comment: @Andrew thanks. I think `_.merge()` would work, though..Updated the answer, although question is closed so it doesn't really matter. (unlike your function, `_.merge()` does merge arrays - whether that makes sense or not depends on what you are trying to do, I guess)